# How to compare UDTs which are not byte ordered?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

I would like to create my own UDT using C# which could be indexed. Unfortunately, it must have own serialization and it can't be byte order (because this UDT is destined to contain many double values).

How can I implement my own comparison?

MSDN claims that implementing Icomparable affects only comparison on client side and SQL Server doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a typical comparison (i.e. A < B), write a CLR function which you can then register as a User Defined Function in SQL Server.  Let's say you write a function that returns -1 if A < B, 0 if A = B, and 1 if A > B.  Then your comparison becomes

```
WHERE (myUserDefinedComparisonFunction(A, B) < 1)
```

In fact, if you go ahead and have your type implement IComparable your CLR comparison code simply becomes

> return A.CompareTo(B);

Comment: But this is not resolving my main problem. I want to make udt which can be indexed and to acomplish this I need comparison